# RegExp for string with repeating tokens

Tags: python, regex

One day I'll master Regexp, but once again I find myself stuck on the Python `re` module.  When I used `;` as a regexp construct, it only returns the `;` characters, which is a bit embarrassing, to be honest.

I wish to split this data-string:

`$POSL;VEL;GPS;040.0;0.1;;;*32`

`;` is the separator, but it's important that I get *empty matches* (null strings) for elements 6 and 7.

So, the output I require would be:

- `"$POSL"`
- `"VEL"`
- `"GPS"`
- `"040.0"`
- `"0.1"`
- `""`
- `""`
- `"*32"`

**Note:** I'm aware that calling `split()` would be easier. But, I need to know the character indices of the tokens - so, for example I know that `VEL` occupies characters 6-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex:

`([^;]+|(?<=;)(?=;)|^(?=;)|(?<=;)$)`

On input:

`;$POSL;VEL;GPS;040.0;0.1;;;*32;;`

Gives:

```
Match 1
1.  Empty
Match 2
1.  $POSL
Match 3
1.  VEL
Match 4
1.  GPS
Match 5
1.  040.0
Match 6
1.  0.1
Match 7
1.  Empty
Match 8
1.  Empty
Match 9
1.  *32
Match 10
1.  Empty
Match 11
1.  Empty
```

https://regex101.com/r/HVrN1M/1

But I think it's much easier to just call `split`.

Comment: > much easier to just call `split`

Absolutely, but I want to know the character indices of each match.  Let me explain that in the question.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. No regex required.

```
inp = '$POSL;VEL;GPS;040.0;0.1;;;*32'
print(inp.split(';'))
```

Answer (score 0):

re.split('delimiter', string) -> the first argument is the delimiter on which you want to split the string and the 2nd argument is the string on which you want this operation.

It returns a list of strings and hence you can use as per your wish.

```
import re

#String s
s="$POSL;VEL;GPS;040.0;0.1;;;*32"

l=re.split(';',s)
print(l)

#['$POSL', 'VEL', 'GPS', '040.0', '0.1', '', '', '*32']
```